# poor s3 upload performance using spark

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I want to verify the results of

```
http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/
```

but using spark. So, far increase the number of partitions results in same or worse upload speed. not even close to the author's 1 GB/sec. Granted, my instance is M1.xlarge, not optimized for network, but still it is rated at 1Gb / sec. And, for this purpose, I am only trying to verify the benefit of partitioning RDD and parallel save of each partition.

My hunch is the limit of concurrent connections, which the article stated to be 2 for Windows server. I am using Amazon linux, for which I have seen  numbers like 20 concurrent connections by default. If that is true, I should see increase if throughput with the experimental parameters I used. Is there a way to verify this number. Or, if its low, how would I increase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is apparently a bad problem with Spark - S3 interface. I repeated the experiment using aws client and threads, just as described in the article, and got a clear performance gain with increasing thread count, And the boost in speed is up to 10 times.